# Different layout display on website over multiple loads

Tags: html, css, zen-cart

I am having an extremely odd issue creating a template for my zencart ecommerce website.

I find that many times I load the website my menu will break up and split over two lines as shown below.

[image]

The reason I find this behavior odd is that if I refresh the page it correctly displays.

[image]

Now I could understand how to fix this if it was consistently one way or the other but it seems to vary between the two with no obvious difference in the code... I am not sure if this is some sort of technical bug with chrome as I haven't been able to replicate it in other browsers however even if it is I really need a way of working around it. So I am curious as to whether anyone has had this issue before and if so how they got around it.

Link to live site: http://digitalmatrixonline.com.au/ 
 
Thanks Jason

Comment: without code...we can not help mate!!!

Comment: dude, jsfiddle :) or link

Comment: Yeah I just realised I forgot to link the site, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

To the div that contains the list it should prevent this, not sure why it's happening though.

**Edit**: here is a jsfiddle showing the technique http://jsfiddle.net/RM4S2/

**Edit**: No floats http://jsfiddle.net/BsGfu/2/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but white-space only applies to text and given that my text is positioned inside DIVs as well as my search form being present this will not correct this issue. I tried applying that css just in case and it does not seem to have helped either.

Comment: It does not only apply to text, please look at the fiddle.

Comment: I have applied this technique and it seems to have not effect on the wrapping. Interestingly enough though when I hover over the div in chrome (inspect element) it doesn't list where "contact us" and the search have wrapped to as part of the div, however despite this is still wraps

Comment: I noticed you had float on them, try removing that.

Comment: I could do that but I am currently positioning those button on the right side of the main nav div using those floats so without them this fix would be largely useless....

Comment: Once you've made something an inline-block you no longer need floats to put it on the right. Any simple text manipulations will work. Such as text-align:right; Check out the js fiddle i just added.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about how I was setting up my menu after you made your comment and you are probably right. Both on it working and to be honest I should probably be removing those floats anyway... I have work tomorrow so I am going to catch some rest now. I have marked your answer as the solution as you have put a lot of effort into helping me , really I wish I could mark both yours and Shawn's answers as correct as they both correct this issue however I feel yours probably works a bit more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really strange problem, and I was able to recreate the quirkiness in Chrome.  While I don't know the direct cause of the issue, I think I found one way that works.

If you set the width of the second div within 'navEZpagesTop' that you are floating right that is wrapping,to 'width:485px;'.  This seems to give the section room and does not wrap.  If you want to leave more room for this expand without modifying the css you could set it to a much larger size, and float all the links inside of this to the right(instead of the left).

Comment: This does indeed seem to be a solution. It would be nice if someone could provide an explanation however if that doesn't happen by the end of the day I will mark your answer as the solution as it does in fact correct my issue. Thank you